# Idiomatic way to select from a matrix based on value

Tags: apl, dyalog

The following `employee` matrix of names and email addresses makes it visually clear that `bob`'s email address is `bob@example.com`.

```
┌───────┬─────────────────────┐
│alice  │alice@example.com    │
├───────┼─────────────────────┤
│bob    │bob@example.com      │
├───────┼─────────────────────┤
│charlie│charlie47@example.com│
└───────┴─────────────────────┘
```

But how do I programmatically access the email address based on a given value in column 1?  The best approach I've found so far is

```
(⊂'bob') {(⍵[;1]⍳⍺) 2 ⌷⍵} employees
```

This *works*, but is pretty verbose—I feel like I must be missing a much simpler way to do something that I would imagine to be fairly common.

Any tips on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways your function could be formulated, but they are all along those tracks:

```apl
(⊂'bob'){(⍺⍳⍨⊣/⍵)⌷⊢/⍵}employee
```

However, using a function may be too much abstraction, since you may want to use the index to extract from a different table;

```apl
employee[employee[;1]⍳⊂'bob';2]
```

For ease of readability, you can name your columns:

```apl
(name email)←⍳2
employee[employee[;name]⍳⊂'bob';email]
```

But the classic way is actually to use a separate array for each column:

```apl
(name email)←↓⍉employee
email⌷⍨name⍳⊂'bob'
```

For more organisation (avoiding polluting the workspace with one name per column) you can collect them in a namespace:

```apl
(Employee←⎕NS⍬).(name email)←↓⍉employee
Employee.(email⌷⍨name⍳⊂)'bob'
```

---

If you want the best database performance, you should designate each column a fixed field-width:

```apl
(name email)←10 30(⊢↑⍨⊢∘≢,⊣)¨↑¨↓⍉employee
email⌷⍨name⍳10↑'bob'
```

Of course, you can put these into a namespace, but you can also store the columns as elements of a vector. This is called an *inverted table*.

```apl
employeeIT←10 30(⊢↑⍨⊢∘≢,⊣)¨↑¨↓⍉employee
(name email)←⍳2
(email⊃employeeIT)⌷⍨(names⊃employeeIT)⍳10↑'bob'
```

---

Another way to achieve high performance is to bind the name list with `⍳` which causes APL to generate a hash table. In fact, you can bind the email list with indexing too and go for a completely functional approach:

```apl
(name email)←↓⍉employee
Name←name∘⍳
Email←⌷∘email
Email Name ⊂'bob'
```

Comment: All very informative, thanks! That last approach is particularly nifty; extrapolating a bit from that makes me realize that I can arbitrarily treat any matrix as a hash table.

Given a matrix with named columns, I can write `⌷∘name1 (name2∘⍳) target` and arbitrarily treat `name2` as a key for the hashtable.  Wow!

(Of course, that only works well if `name2` is unique, but it's still far better than a language where hashmaps have only one fixed key)

Answer (score 0):

This seems more long...

```
  A←3 2⍴('Alice')('ralice@1')('bob')('abob@2')('charlie')('gchiarli@3')
  A
Alice   ralice@1   
bob     abob@2     
charlie gchiarli@3 
  q←{C←⍺⋄0=+/D←{C≡⍵}¨↑¨B←{{w[⍵;]}¨⍳≢w←⍵}⍵:⍬⋄↑1↓↑D/B}
  ⎕fmt ('charlie') q A
┌10─────────┐
│ gchiarli@3│
└───────────┘
  ⎕fmt ('') q A
┌0─┐
│ 0│
└~─┘
  ⎕fmt ('1') q A
┌0─┐
│ 0│
└~─┘
  ⎕fmt (1) q A
┌0─┐
│ 0│
└~─┘
  ⎕fmt 1 q A
┌0─┐
│ 0│
└~─┘
  ⎕fmt 'bob' q A
┌6──────┐
│ abob@2│
└───────┘
```